# Unwanted jars in my war

Tags: maven-2

I have not mentioned any dependencies in pom.xml, but the war created by maven has quite a few unwanted jars. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your `pom.xml` file, to be more helpful.

However, you may have some [transitive dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) here.

You can see the whole dependency tree using the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html).

Answer (score 0):

> I have not mentioned any dependencies in pom.xml, but the war created by maven has quite a few unwanted jars. Any idea why this is happening?

Hard to say without seeing your POM but if you didn't declare **any** dependency, then you my bet would be that are inheriting them. Just in case, it is possible to exclude things in the war plugin configuration using the [`packagingExcludes`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#packagingExcludes) optional parameter. But the real question is "why are you inheriting dependencies that you don't want".